# Как сделать рестарт уровня по нажатие R на клавиатуре в unity 2021

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать рестарт уровня по нажатие R на клавиатуре в юнити в c# юнити в 3д игре

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Comment: как сделать рестарт уровня по нажатие R на клавиатуре в юнити в c# юнити в 3д игре

Comment: Это утверждение или вопрос? Если второе - что именно у Вас не получается? Где код? К документации Unity или GOOGLE обращались?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно перезапускать сцену.

Добавляешь в заголовок:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Это в апдейт:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
  SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```